# Tabular edged don't close

Tags: tabularx

I have a very particular problem. I wrote my PhD in a certain style but now the publishing agency asked me to use their stylesheet. 
Since applying it, one of the problems I got is that the edges of my tables don't close anymore :

[image]

When I use \begin{tabularx}, the tables look fine, but in this case, I need to use \begin{tabular} so I can specify that each column can be max. 3.4mm (otherwise the table goes over the edge of the page with no linebreak happening).

Here the code :

```
\documentclass[openany,french]{book}
  \usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
  \usepackage{slantsc}
  \usepackage{longtable} 
   \usepackage{tablefootnote}
  \usepackage{tabularx,latblex}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{adjustbox}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{multirow}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{center}
      \begin{small}
       \begin{tabular}{|>{\arraybackslash}p{3.4cm}|>{\arraybackslash}p{3.4cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.4cm}|}
    \textbf{Suffixe en graphie classique} & \textbf{Suffixe en graphie phonématique} & \textbf{Nombre de lexèmes}\\
    \hline
    \textit{-\={a}tus} & */-\textquotesingle{}at-u/ & 22 \\
    \hline
    \textit{-bilis} & */\textquotesingle{}-βil-e/ & 8 \\
    \hline
    \textit{-ium} & */\textquotesingle{}-i-u/ & 53 \\
    \hline
    \textit{-ivus} & */\textquotesingle{}-iβ-u/ & 7 \\
    \hline
    \textit{-m\u{e}ntum} & */-\textquotesingle{}mɛnt-u/ & 27 \\ 
    \hline
    \textit{-or(e)} & */-\textquotesingle{}or-e/ & 70 \\
    \hline
    \textit{-\={o}ria}/\textit{-\={o}rium}/\textit{-\={o}rius}  &    */-\textquotesingle{}ori-a/ / */-\textquotesingle{}ori-u/ & 44 \\
       \hline
    \textit{-\={u}ra} & */-\textquotesingle{}ur-a/ & 54\\
   \end{tabular}
   \captionof{table}{Nomenclature IV}\label{nomenclature4}
\end{small}
  \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

I guess it must be due to the .sty file I have to use, because in a simple layout it works fine. The only thing about tabular I could find is the following :

```
\RequirePackage{tabularx}[2014/05/13]
\def\TX@endtabularx{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
   \expandafter\TX@newcol\expandafter{\tabularxcolumn{\TX@col@width}}%
  \let\verb\TX@verb
  \def\@elt##1{\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
  \edef\TX@ckpt{\cl@@ckpt}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \TX@old@table\maxdimen
  \TX@col@width\TX@target
   \global\TX@cols\@ne
   \TX@typeout@
    {\@spaces Table Width\@spaces Column Width\@spaces X Columns}%
   \TX@trial{\def\NC@rewrite@X{%
           \global\advance\TX@cols\@ne\NC@find p{\TX@col@width}}}%
   \loop
     \TX@arith
     \ifTX@
     \TX@trial{}%
   \repeat
  {\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
    \csname tabular*\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\TX@target
     \the\toks@
   \csname endtabular*\endcsname}%
 \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
 \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \TX@find@endtabularxbb
   \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
   \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb}
```

Here you can see the full .sty file : [dgruyter.sty](https://github.com/blockchain-lab/shared_vision_towards_programmable_economy/blob/master/tex/dgruyter.sty)

Can anyone help?

Comment: don't post disconnected fragments, (and mostly the source of `tabularx` which you are not using)  post a small but complete document that people can run to see the problem, then it should be easy to debug and help.

Comment: the heavy top and bottom rule, and the side rules are not from the code you show.

Comment: Hope now it's clearer...

Comment: Oh that style:(  Line 24 completely breaks latex (I reported it to them years ago but it still seems to be the same...)

Comment: Try issuing `\baretabulars` in the preamble after `\usepackage{dgruyter}`. (Fished out from memory, can't test now.)

Comment: I tried your example with lualatex and it gives the error `! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\addfontfeatures' already defined!` as it is a commercial publisher class I suggest that you report it to them. (you coudl ask again that they fix `\p@=1bp\relax` as well...

Comment: @Sigur yes This has come up on this site and elsewhere before but any code using dimens as a stand in for floating point arithmetic (eg any scaling or rotation  by the graphics package) will be broken.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I oversaw two books from my boss with that style and I made them aware of that. We had exactly the problem that scaling of figures broke down. They simply don't care.

Comment: @campa \baretabulars works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

\baretabulars in the preamble after \usepackage{dgruyter} works perfectly to make the tables look as they should be.

Comment: @Sebastiano This _is_ an answer to the question. `dgruyter.sty` redefines `tabular` but provides `\baretabulars` to restore LaTeX's original definitions.

Comment: @campa Can I restore my flag? Excuse me for my mistake. I have removed my delete. I hope that the answer not will delete.

Comment: @Sebastiano Nothing to be sorry about. I know it only because I've had to do with this sorry style before `:-)`

Comment: @campa I reiterate my apology also with another method :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does the publisher require the vertical lines, and the horizontal lines between rows?

I ask because the `.sty` file uses the `booktabs` package which is designed to work without any vertical lines.

The documentation is [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), or [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/translations/booktabs/fr/f-booktabs.pdf) for the French version. It contains a long essay about why you shouldn't use vertical lines in tables, and why it makes no attempt to make them join up. If the publisher has used the `booktabs` package, this suggests to me that they don't want verrical lines.